# Any Alternative way to get Hardware Accelerated AMD-V on windows?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, android-studio, vt-x, hardware-virtualization, windows-10-v1903

In an attempt to enable **AMD-V on the Windows platform** in Android studio, I was wondering *What will happen if,*

1. Firstly we enable virtualization from BIOS
2. Then we turn on WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux)
3. Then we install Linux from windows store
4. We use Xfce/Xorg to have the GUI ready
5. Lastly, we install android studio

> Will we be able to, use native AMD-V support on windows?
>
> > Or is there an alternative way to get Native Support of AMD-V?

```
Current PC Config:
    Processor:  AMD A6-9200 7th Generation Dual Core @ 2.70 GHz
          RAM:  8 GB DDR4 2400MHz
     Graphics:  1GB Internal DAC
           OS:  Windows 10 - 1903
 Laptop Model:  Dell Inspiron 3565
```

Comment: `AMD-V is not supported on the Windows platform in Android studio` this is wrong. See [Android Emulator - AMD Processor & Hyper-V Support](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/07/android-emulator-amd-processor-hyper-v.html). See also [Run Android studio emulator on AMD processor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31366453/995714)

Comment: I didn't know this before as I was primarily using an older version of Android Studio. Thanks for pointing out. ☺ Reworded the question.

Comment: Why do you need WSL with Android Studio? And if you focused in Android Development and want to work in GNU/Linux world then you can use a real Linux distribution.

Comment: Your question is not exactly clear.